# Why protected route in my react app doen't work well

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to make protected route in my app to divide routes into (user/admin), but when we get into specific forbidden route, browser enter this forbidden route after that, get out to login page (default when unallowed access).

```
function App() {
  const [isUser, isAdmin, userData] = ProtectedRouteHook()

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbarpage />
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
        <Route path="/allcategory" element={<Allcategories />} />
        <Route path="/allbrands" element={<Allbrands />} />
        <Route path="/products" element={<Productsview />} />
        <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
        <Route path="/order/paymethod" element={<Paymethod />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />

        <Route element={<ProtectedRoute auth={isUser}/>} >
          <Route path="/user/allorders" element={ <Allorders />} />
          <Route path="/user/favoriteproducts" element={<Favoriteproducts />} />
          <Route path="/user/profile" element={<Profile />} />
          <Route path="/user/addresses" element={<Addresses />} />
          <Route path="/user/addAddress" element={<AddAddress />} />
          <Route path="/user/forgetpassword" element={<Forgetpassword/>}/>
          <Route path="/user/verifycode" element={<Verifypassword/>} />
          <Route path="/user/resetpassword" element={<Resetpassword/>} />
        </Route>
        
        <Route element={<ProtectedRoute auth={isAdmin}/>}>
          <Route path="/admin/allproducts" element={<Allproducts />} />
          <Route path="/admin/manage-orders" element={<Manageorders />} />
          <Route path="/admin/add-brand" element={<Addbrand />} />
          <Route path="/admin/add-category" element={<Addcategory />} />
          <Route path="/admin/add-subCategory" element={<Addsubcategory />} />
          <Route path="/admin/add-product" element={<Addproduct />} />
          <Route exact path="/products/:id" element={<Productdetails />} />
          <Route exact path="/admin/order/:id" element={<OrderDetails />} /> 
        </Route>
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from 'react'
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'

const ProtectedRoute = ({ auth, children }) => {
  if (auth === false) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" replace />
  }
  return children ? children : <Outlet />
}

export default ProtectedRoute
```

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const ProtectedRouteHook = () => {
  const [userData, _setUserData] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")))
  const [isUser, setIsUser] = useState()
  const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userData != null) {
      if (userData.role === "user") {
        setIsUser(true)
        setIsAdmin(false)
      } else {
        setIsUser(false)
        setIsAdmin(true)
      }
    } else {
      setIsAdmin(false)
      setIsUser(false)
    }
  }, [])

  return [isUser, isAdmin, userData]
}

export default ProtectedRouteHook
```

When person browse my website there are routes to specific users, they should login to get (local storage contains user data especially role of user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is a mismatch of the initial `isUser` and `isAdmin` states (*both initially `undefined`*) and the protected route condition that explicitly checks for `false` `auth` prop value. `undefined === false` is `false`

```js
console.log(undefined === false);
```

So the `ProtectedRoute` route component renders the `children` prop or the `Outlet` component and the "protected" content is accessible while the user is  not authenticated.

## Solution

The solutions here are to either provide valid initial state values or conditionally wait to render the protected content or redirect.

### Proper Initial State

In this specific scenario it is easy/trivial to fix since accessing localStorage is synchronous and the `ProtectedRouteHook` component can use `userData` to directly initialize the `isUser` and `isAdmin` states.

Example:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const ProtectedRouteHook = () => {    
  const [userData, _setUserData] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")));

  const [isUser, setIsUser] = useState(userData?.role === "user");
  const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(userData && userData.role !== "user");

  return [isUser, isAdmin, userData];
}

export default ProtectedRouteHook;
```

Actually, since `isUser` and `isAdmin` are *technically* considered derived state, they shouldn't be stored in any React state, simply return the computed derived state values.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const ProtectedRouteHook = () => {    
  const [userData, _setUserData] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")));

  return [
    userData?.role === "user", // isUser
    userData && userData.role !== "user", // isAdmin
    userData
  ];
}

export default ProtectedRouteHook;
```

### Conditionally wait until Auth Status is Confirmed

While the `auth` prop value is still `undefined` render `null` or some loading indicator while the user's authentication status is confirmed.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'

const ProtectedRoute = ({ auth, children }) => {
  if (auth === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return auth
    ? children || <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
}

export default ProtectedRoute
```